# xpath query multiple conditions

Tags: xpath, xpathquery

```
<div class='table-wrap'>
<table class='dashTable'><tbody>
<tr>
<td class='dashBoard'><b>ID</b></td>
<td class='dashBoard'><b>Name</b></td>
<td class='dashBoard'><b>TEP</b></td>
<td class='dashBoard'><b>Status</b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class='dashBoard'>001</td>
<td class='dashBoard'>Liam</td>
<td class='dashBoard'><font color="#00875a"><b>2-Nov-2022 1 PM CET</b> </font></td>
<td class='dashBoard'> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class='dashBoard'>002</td>
<td class='dashBoard'> <b><font color="#00875a">Noah</font></b></td>
<td class='dashBoard'>  <b><font color="#00875a">2-Nov-2022 1 PM CET</font></b> </td>
<td class='dashBoard'> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class='dashBoard'>003</td>
<td class='dashBoard'> <b><font color="#00875a">James</font></b></td>
<td class='dashBoard'><font color="#00875a"><b>2-Nov-2022 1 PM CET</b> </font></td>
<td class='dashBoard'> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class='dashBoard'>004</td>
<td class='dashBoard'>Lucas<br/>
 <del>Lauren</del><br/>
 <b><font color="#00875a">Lucie</font></b></td>
<td class='dashBoard'>   <b><font color="#00875a">2-Nov-2022 6 PM JST</font></b></td>
<td class='dashBoard'> </td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</div>
```

I'm trying to write a query by which from every `td[2]` I will grab only the element `b[font]`, but if `td[2]` does not have `b[font]`, then it should select the entire `td[2]` attribute with all its elements.

I've stopped on this, the query finds only `b[font]`, but skips `td[2]` if there are no child elements:

```
//div[@class="table-wrap"]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/b[font]
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This XPath will get elements as requested

```
//div[@class="table-wrap"]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/b[font] | //div[@class="table-wrap"]/table/tbody/tr/td[position()=2 and not(b[font])]
```

Result

```
<td class="dashBoard"><b>Name</b></td>
<td class="dashBoard">Liam</td>
<b><font color="#00875a">Noah</font></b>
<b><font color="#00875a">James</font></b>
<b><font color="#00875a">Lucie</font></b>
```